# How to detect when user opens the OS X Notification Center?

Tags: macos, cocoa

How do I detect when a user opens the OS X Mountain Lion Notification Center?

Is there an NSNotification (ugh, very similar term for a different thing) which I can observe?

Comment: I initially thought this might be accomplished by checking `[[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame]`, but this does not seem to adjust for the Notification Center drawer (OS X 10.9).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

<s>I don't know of any officially documented solution or notification (let me know!), but this appeared to work (at least on OS X 10.10) when I tested it, so long as my application was in the foreground/had the frontmost window I believe.</s>

Add your object as an observer:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationCenterOpened:) name:@"com.apple.HIToolbox.beginMenuTrackingNotification" object:nil];

[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationCenterClosed:) name:@"com.apple.HIToolbox.endMenuTrackingNotification" object:nil];
```

Add methods similar to the following to your object, making sure to check for the correct `ToolboxMessageEventData` number (`4927`), for example:

```
- (void)notificationCenterOpened:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if ([notification.userInfo[@"ToolboxMessageEventData"] isEqual: @4927]) {
        NSLog(@"Notification center opened");
    }
}

- (void)notificationCenterClosed:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if ([notification.userInfo[@"ToolboxMessageEventData"] isEqual: @4927]) {
        NSLog(@"Notification center closed");
    }
}
```

Let me know if that does or doesn't work for you.

Nevermind - upon restart/log-off + log back in, the ToolboxMessageEventData appears to change.